# d3.js foreignObject text transition

Tags: text, d3.js, transition

I am using d3.js to build a little project that involves data, shapes and text. According to the data, the text appears inside of a shape. If you mouse-over the shape, the shape should become larger and show more text.

The text is added in the following manner and it works fine:

```
Shapes  
.append("foreignObject")
[...]
.append("xhtml:body")
.style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
.html(function(d) {return d.text;   });
```

I use foreignObject rather than text because I need the text to line-wrap and this is the only way that I've so far been able to achieve this effect.

What's giving me grief is the mouse-over. I can re-size the shape just fine but I am having trouble calling a transition on the text. In fact, I don't really know how to access it successfully.

Here is some of the code from the mouse-over event:

```
d3.select(this)         
.transition()
.duration(250)
.attr("height", function(d,i) {
    d.showAll()
    //d.textObject.width = 4;
    return d.height; 
} );

d3.select(this).select("foreignObject").transition()
.duration(250)
.select("xhtml:body")
.html(function(d) {return d.text;   });
```

The idea is that the showAll() function has already changed the text to a new value, however the code does not get that far. The message that Chrome gives me is "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'html' ".

So, how do I access the text and update it so that my transition will lead to the new text being visible and the old text disappearing?

I've been banging my head against this for a while so any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: If I understood correctly what you're doing, `this` should already refer to the `foreignObject`. So `d3.select(this).select("foreignObject")` probably doesn't do what you think it does -- did you verify that all your selections are what you think they should be?

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the comment. To be honest, I'm not really sure how to verify whether the snippet above does what I think it does... I don't think it does what I think it does because its not doing the job I wrote it to do - but I don't know why. The 'this', however, refers to the rect because the rect's height is indeed changed as a result of the call.

Comment: You can check by printing the result with `console.log()`.

Comment: Hi again, I can't seem to get that console.log() to do anything - it's supposed to display the argument in the console, right? Still trying to 'get a hold' of the text.

Comment: Yes, it should display things in the console -- something like `console.log(d3.select(this).select("foreignObject"))`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything at all. Even when I just do console.log("blah blah"), I don't see any output in the console - not in Chrome and not in Mozilla.

Comment: Ok, so the code where you put it isn't executed at all. That might give you a hint already :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace d3.select(this).select("foreignObject") with d3.selectAll(this.getElementsByTagName("foreignObject"))

I just solved this myself and thought I would help.